# PostgreSQL 9.3 sql result: long text has shortened

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to SELECT some text that so long (about 500~ char), when using pg-admin > sql to test my sql, its return result which has shortened (about 250 char + '(...)').

Anybody know how to config PostgreSQL to always show fully text result ?

Thank you.

**Updated**

```
my_table(
  my_column text;
)

INSERT INTO my_table(my_column) VALUES ('this is long(500~ char more) long text');
SELECT my_column FROM my_table
```

**output pane display:**
-> `this is long(250~ char more) (...)`

I think this will more clearly :)

Comment: "pgsql"???  `pg-admin`?  `psql`?

Comment: Use a text mode client, use psql. You are writing sql, so you should know that the display in a GUI is not configured in the database itself.

Comment: psql does not support Unicode character, big trouble for me :), my alt way, use "execute query, write result to file", get ".cvs" file, this is contains my fully result, but it will slowdown my working process. Why postgresql 8.4 can but 9.3 can not :-?

Comment: I'm working with json data store as text in database, so, i need fully text result, then copy/paste to notepad++ and test it with JSONTool plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pgadmin go in the menù:

**File --> options**

Under "**Query tool**", select "**Query editor**".

In the box "**Max Characters per column**", insert... a big number :-)

Maximum is 2147483647, but it can consume a lot of memory in some case... Anyway, if it is not a production server you have not to worry.